SOAP webservice with Spring boot, Java 11 and JBOSS 7.4
in our project, we are using Spring boot 2.7.11 with Java11 (Jakarta EE instead of Java EE) to develop a SOAP web service (this is required from the consumer side to stick to SOAP instead of REST) which calls the vendor product EJB APIs. I have upgraded the old code to work with the new ecosystem when running with the embedded Tomcat server of Spring boot and the request/response of SOAP works properly. However, when the WAR file is deployed on a JBOSS EAP (after excluding Spring boot starter Tomcat), the endpoint does not work and gives 404 error or 403 Forbidden error on different URIs. Simply put, I am unable to know what is the SOAP endpoint (URI) when deployed on a JBOSS EAP server. I tried using @Endpoint, @EnableWs, @Webservice, Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/ws", new CustomWebService()); but nothing seems to work. Did anyone worked on the same technologies or know how to hit the correct endpoint? This is the must- have technology stack: Spring boot (any version will do), Java 11 (preferably OpenJDK11), webservice with SOAP framework, JBOSS EAP 7.4.
Not to distract but this is what I did which I am uncomfortable with. Earlier, I intended to get all the maven dependencies from Spring initializr, however, now it does not give the option of using Java 11, hence took the pom.xml from an earlier project with Spring boot 2.7.11 and then added dependencies for Jakarta EE as needed. Fortunately, the flows work with Apache Tomcat but not with JBOSS EAP 7.4, so I am not sure if this is a maven dependency problem or a JBOSS-specific issue. Please help with your suggestions as I am stuck for a week without concrete progress.
